# Laravel 5 - Config sub-folder

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, we can read a config value via this:

```
config('app.url')
```

But, how can we read config file value in the sub-folder? I have tried with `config('subfolder/app.url')` but it didn't work.

Comment: I never have seen that structure, try still using dot notation

Answer (score 9):

You can do like this in laravel 5  `config('subfolder.myfile.var')`; `subfolder` is folder name , `myfile` is your file name and `var`  is your variable.

Answer (score 3):

I've created: config/local/app.php containing:

`<?php 
    return [
       "key" => "value"
    ];`

and using artisan, here's what i got:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create Folder with name **subfolder** inside **config** directory create file **app.php**

Inside app.php put all your constants

```
return array(
        'APP_URL'  => 'http://www.test.com/xyz',
        'APP_MAX_FOLDER_SIZE' => 1000000000,
);
```

and access like

```
config('subfolder.app.APP_URL');
```

it is advisable to create constants in **Upper case** letter and create file name that makes sense like **constans.php** or **appconstants.php** etc

Comment: Array keys are not constants.

Answer (score 0):

> for Lumen developers

Just in case someone need it. This is the way I was able to do it:

Step 1 - Create the sub directory under config/ for example validator

Step 2 - Create the configuration files: messages.php, rules.php

```
config
└── validator
    ├── messages.php
    └── rules.php
```

Step 3 - Enable the configuration files under bootsrap/app.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Custom Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Register custom configuration files that are under config/
|
*/
$app->configure('validator/messages');
$app->configure('validator/rules');

/**/
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

Step 4 - Get the configuration

```
config('validator/rules.key');
```

ref: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/config-in-subdirectory